# mySQL. How do I dump only new/updated row of a table?

Tags: mysql

working with mySQL, is there a general way to dump just new or update rows of a db/table, when I can not alter the DB with new columns/fields.

How would you go to write a script to do that? Is out there any piece of code I may hack?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have anything that automatically keeps track of new and updated rows. You need to have a column that contains the last update time, then you can use that in a `WHERE` clause to find changed rows.

Comment: You could add a trigger to every table that adds the ID of an inserted or updated row to a logging table.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know [SJA](http://faq.webyog.com/content/27/114/en/introduction-to-the-_sqlyog-job-agent_-sja.html)? It does exactly what I was asking for. Do you happen to know how it makes it possible?